# Assets in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've updated my Rails 3.2 app to 4.0 version and have stumbled upon one problem.
When I run the site with `config.assets.compile = false` option it doesn't load any assets. I've tried `rake assets:precompile` and it compiles assets at `public/assets`, but site doesn't load any of those. I've got `application.js` and `application.css` included in my layout, but when I check the source of the page, it's said that they are not found.
 
When I run the site with `config.assets.compile = true` everything works perfectly, but I've read that turning this off will result in greater performance, so I need to get it work. 
Thanks in advance.
**UPD:** I've found that if I'm using this command `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` everything works. The question is why the `rake assets:precompile` command doesn't working?
**UPD2:** For those, who have the same issue, here's the explanation.
Regular `rake assets:precompile` compiles assets for application that runs in development mode. Specifying `RAILS_ENV=production` part in the beginning makes the command to compile assets for production mode, the `bundle exec` part is not required. So the final command looks like this: `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`. Maybe it was obvious, but it took me a while to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Show how you're including application.js/css.

Comment: I include it like this: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Comment: so you got it working or what? if you are not using `bundle exec` and you have an old version of rails installed, it's possible that this gets invoked. but it's just a wild guess. did you use the asset-helpers in any of your stylesheets and javascripts? thats the most common problem of missing assets with rails4.

Comment: Yes, I got it working, the only question is: why the `rake assets:precompile` doesn't work?